# Why does this SQL query return NULL?

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
var_dump($result);
```

It displays NULL when I run it on my webpage.
I have no clue what's wrong and it is really annoying.

Comment: turn on error reporting to get more info or check your error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)`, you have to give the connection to the db as a parameter. Such as

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

It is from a statement earlier, such as

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

You should have this line in your script, before the query.

Answer (score 1):

> mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode);

You must provide a valid connection.

Something like

```
$con=mysqli_connect("my_host","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Customer");
```

Look at the reference https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

And remember to check the connection and to free the result

Comment: It is connected to the database. It returns no error when executing the query, it just wont let me get the result (I think). https://pastebin.com/maE3UZQc

Comment: Ok, it is connected. But you have to pass the connection to the query.

Comment: @Oscar Vincenzo means you did not pass the connection as a parameter to [mysqli_query](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) (see, the first parameter when using the procedural style - as you do - is the connection).

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (NameOfdatabase).Customer";
```

try this

Comment: Still displaying NULL.